# How to fix ' ReferenceError: $ is not defined' while showing result of api in Node Js '

Tags: node.js, api, referenceerror

I am trying to get the result from an api and show it in an html page . I have included body-parser and app.use method.But as soon as i enter value and submit ,i am getting the error : ReferenceError: flightStatus is not defined . The api usage is successfull , I am a beginner , so please pardon if it is a fstupid question . Any help is greatly appreciated !  Here is my server code :

```
app.post("/iatatracker", function (req, res) {

    console.log(req);

    
    let apiKey = 'somekey';
    let iataQuery = req.body.iatacode; 
    let airlineIcaoQuery = req.body.flighticao;
    let url = `http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=${apiKey}&airline_icao=${airlineIcaoQuery}&flight_iata=${iataQuery}`;
    http.get(url, function (response) {
    
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            let flightData = JSON.parse(data);
            let flightStatus = flightData.data.flight_status;
            console.log(flightStatus);
    
    
        });
    })
    
    res.write(` The ${flightStatus}`);
}
```

Here is my html form code

```
 <form class="form" name="iata" action="/iatatracker" method="POST"  onsubmit="validateForm()">

        <label for="iatacode"> Enter IATA Code : (for example : 6E881) </label>
        <input type="text" name="iatacode" id="iatacode">

        <label for="flighticao"> Enter Flight ICAO Code : (for eg: igo for Indigo Airlines) </label>
        <input type="text" name="flighticao" id="flighticao">

        <button class="btn" type="submit"> Check Flight History </button>
```

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

So from your code I can get is you are trying to access `flightStatus` variable out of its scope.

You can use `` res.write(` The ${flightStatus}`); `` inside your `response.on` function's callback function as below.

```
http.get(url, function (response) {

        response.on('data', function (data) {
            let flightData = JSON.parse(data);
            let flightStatus = flightData.data.flight_status;
            console.log(flightStatus);
            res.write(` The ${flightStatus}`);

        });
    });
```

**Solution 2:** Taking reference from [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)'s comment.

You can create a function to pass the data from `response.on`'s callback function as below:

```
http.get(url, function (response) {

        response.on('data', function (data) {
            let flightData = JSON.parse(data);
            let flightStatus = flightData.data.flight_status;
            console.log(flightStatus);
            sendResponse(flightStatus);

        });
    });

function sendResponse(flightStatus) {
    res.write(` The ${flightStatus}`);
}
```

Let me know in comment if this solves your issue.

Comment: Even declaring `flightStatus` at a higher scope would not do any good because it wouldn't yet have a value when they try to use it.  Using that value INSIDE the callback where it becomes available or calling a function from there and passing the value to that function are the two ways to use it in this code.

Comment: Thanks for your review I have edited my answer according to your suggested way.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! everyone .  I tried both of the steps, but now it says the nodemon has crashed , Can you help me with this?  undefined:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\2kwattz\Desktop\2kaerostack\server.js:40:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:527:10)
    at flow (node:internal/streams/readable:1012:34)
   
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...